# Issues with Internet Explorer and background not showing

Tags: css

I'm having a few issues with my background not showing for my button elements.

Here's my CSS code:

```
button.button-master-lite, a.button-master-lite {
    background: #92AE41;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #89A73E 0%, #92AE41 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#89A73E), to(#92AE41));

    border: 1px solid #89A73E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #92AE41;

    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #92AE41;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #92AE41;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #92AE41;

    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;

    padding: 5px 8px 6px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #5D862F;
    width: auto;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<a class="button-master-lite" href="#">Order Now</a>
```

With IE 6 and IE 7 the background-color does not show. However, when I take off the other background declarations except the first one, the background shows.

The HTML page I have this button on has a number of divs and sub-divs with floats and position style elements, but I can't figure out which one is causing the issue. I tried putting the code on a completely blank page with only my stylesheet and it worked ok.

Is there anything in particular that would be causing the background not to show when I have other background declarations for other browsers?! Does it have anything to do with floats or other positioning elements?

I'd appreciate some assistance. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can combine your font-family, font-size, font-weight, and line-height rules into a [single declaration](http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-primer-on-the-css-font-shorthand-property/): `font:bold 11px/1 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using background-color and background-image properties like so:

```
button.button-master-lite, a.button-master-lite {
    background-color: #92AE41;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #89A73E 0%, #92AE41 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#89A73E), to(#92AE41));
    border: 1px solid #89A73E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #92AE41; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #92AE41;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #92AE41; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #92AE41; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 1; 
    padding: 5px 8px 6px 8px; 
    text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #5D862F; 
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're resetting the background right after you set it. Use `background-color` for setting the color and then `background-image` for those CSS3 gradients.

Demo: http://codetester.org/2cef201d

This site helps a lot!
http://css3please.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` or `display:inline-block`

Comment: not sure why i got the downvote for? it could be a possible property that he may have missed and cause the background not to show since anchor tags are inline elements

Comment: I'm guessing you were downvoted because he was talking about the *color* not showing.  display block or inline has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I upvoted your comment. While the question may be about color not showing, display properties can and do have an affect on such things, especially with non-block-level elements such as the "a" tag...

Comment: I had the same problem even when using button and a tags even with display:block defined. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: No problem just trying to help out..but if you were using a A tag with display:block you were probably missing width and height